# Roblox Studio Lua Problem "Workspace.Ultimate.Script:12: attempt to compare number < string"-

Tags: lua, compare, roblox

```
deb = true
giv = script.Parent.Giver
function touch(part)
    local hum = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if hum then
        local plr = game.Players:FindFirstChild(part.Parent.Name)
        local ls = plr:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
        local cash = ls:FindFirstChild("Cash")
        if plr then
            if deb == true then
                if cash.Value > 12500 then
                deb = false
                giv.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
                    local weapon = game.ReplicatedStorage.Jutsus:FindFirstChild("Fireball")
                local w2 = weapon:Clone()
                w2.Parent = plr.Backpack
                wait(script.Parent.RegenTime.Value)
                giv.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright violet")
                    deb = true
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
script.Parent.Giver.Touched:connect(touch)
```

I'm Stuck at this Point, i Tried so much things but nothing Worked the Output is this:

```
Workspace.Ultimate.Script:12: attempt to compare number < string  -  Server - Script:12
```

I would really appreciate it if someone would improve the code for me.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously `cash.Value` is a string so you cannot do `cash.Value > 12500`.

Convert `cash.Value` to a number befor comparing it to a number.

`tonumber(cash.Value) > 12500`.

This solution assumes that `cash.Value` is a string representing a number. If this is not the case you have to ensure that first.

Answer (score 0):

String and number comparison needs to be converted in advance, and you need to make sure `casg.Value` must be a number, otherwise you may be prompted to compare with a nil value

Then you can write code like this.

```
deb = true
giv = script.Parent.Giver
function touch(part)
    local hum = part.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid")
    if hum then
        local plr = game.Players:FindFirstChild(part.Parent.Name)
        local ls = plr:FindFirstChild("leaderstats")
        local cash = ls:FindFirstChild("Cash")
        if plr then
            if deb == true then
                if (tonumber(cash.Value) or 0) > 12500 then
                    deb = false
                    giv.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really red")
                    local weapon = game.ReplicatedStorage.Jutsus:FindFirstChild("Fireball")
                    local w2 = weapon:Clone()
                    w2.Parent = plr.Backpack
                    wait(script.Parent.RegenTime.Value)
                    giv.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Bright violet")
                    deb = true
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
script.Parent.Giver.Touched:connect(touch)
```